# Forward(request,response) doesn't forward the URL

Tags: java, servlets, forward

I'm doing a project using Java servlets. I have to include  code in an already functioning site. I'm using Netbeans and the server is Tomcat. The code that I added is very similar to some parts of the code of the site. I had to create a new controller that reads from a database and display, add, update and delete information. The site was functioning with different servlets that we created but a requisite for the project is to create the controller servlet.  This is part of the code of the controller:

```
public class MaintController extends HttpServlet {

   @Override
    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response)
            throws IOException, ServletException {

       String requestURI = request.getRequestURI();
        String url = "/maint";
        if (requestURI.endsWith("/displayProducts")) {
            url = displayProducts(request, response);
        } else if (requestURI.endsWith("/addProduct")) {
            url = addProduct(request, response);
        } else if (requestURI.endsWith("/editProduct")) {
            url = editProduct(request, response);
        } else if (requestURI.endsWith("/deleteProduct")){
            deleteProduct(request, response);
        }

       getServletContext()
                .getRequestDispatcher(url)
                .forward(request, response);
    }

    private String displayProducts(HttpServletRequest request, 
            HttpServletResponse response)
            throws  IOException, ServletException  {

        HttpSession session = request.getSession();

         List<Product> products = ProductDB.selectProducts();
        session.setAttribute("products", products);
        out.println(products);
        String url= "/maint/products.jps";

        return url;
    }
```

The point is that debugging the site I can see that when entering an URL that finishes with `/displayProducts` the `displayProducts` function is accessed, the products are read and the URL is returned, but when the control goes to `getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher(url).forward(request, response);` the url is not forwarded and I get a 404 error when the url exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see in the displayProducts() method, you have defined the url as follows:

```
String url= "/maint/products.jps";
```

shouldn't that be a typo??

```
String url= "/maint/products.jsp";
```

file extension is wrong right?

Comment: yes, the file extension was wrong and I couldn't see it
thank you

Answer (score 0):

404 error indicates the requested page not found. 
your return url is

```
String url= "/maint/products.jps";
```

extension of the requested page is not correct. It should be products.jsp